# Warn message in nhprofiler WARN: No persister No mapped documents found in assembly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have tier application divided into three projects one have mapping files the second have classes and the final project is for presentation and I created mappings using fluent nhibernate.
when I run my application all things operate correctly except Warn Message that display in nhprofiler that is WARN: No persister No mapped documents found in assembly.

anyone have idea why this message displayed?